# Does an Extended Validation (EV) Code Signing Certificate protect the downloader if the installer is compromised

Tags: security, installation, certificate, installer, code-signing

A friend of mine has some software available on his website and the installer for it has been infected with some malware. The infection happened on the hosted server without my friend knowing. Obviously a serious very issue.

I have some software that is available for download. I am thinking of using an Extended Validation (EV) Code Signing Certificate. The main advertised advantage is that it gives users more confidence to install your software. There are less warnings.

At the moment I don't have a signed installer. If I do use one AND the installer gets infected by malware is the downloader any better off? Will they see anything different to what they see now? It would be simple for the malware to hide any signing -- just xor stuff in the exe. If it just wraps the installer in its malware, will the user see anything different or get a different warning?

Comment: All a EV certificate can be used for is to identify, this file was signed by the developer, if the developer is malicious it can still be signed by a EV certificate. Installers don’t get infected with malware, servers are compromised by malicious parties, and replaced with a malicious copy. What you describe wouldn’t have been prevented even if the file was signed, since the server would have still been compromised, and left undiscovered

Comment: It is harder to get an EV cert, so it does offer some additional protection to the brand, provided that they handle the cert securely and don't let anyone else get their hands on it, but for code signing certs, someone has to bother to check the certificate. if someone replaced the installer with one signed using a non-EV cert, its unlikely anyone would notice without direct inspection.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Validation_Certificate#Issuing_criteria

Comment: @Ramhound so, it seem that there is little gain for the downloader. If they see 'Signed by xxx' then that is a good sign. An infected installer won't be signed - but is that any different from an unsigned uninfected installer?

Comment: @Rob—A malicious party can sign the file themselves, masquerade as the developer, and don't even have to have an EV certificate. If a malicious file replaces the signed file, the end user will be none the wiser.  The CCleaner installer was signed by Piriform a few years ago, but that didn't stop Piriform from being compromised and their installer being infected.  Microsoft and Google warn browsers users based on the file reputation; a file's reputation is more positive if it's signed, and signing your installer is good practice.  Preventing the server compromise in the first place is a must.

Comment: @Ramhound are there any alternatives? I am being pushed to sign because it reduces friction for the downloader. I would really prefer the situation to be more secure

Comment: @Rob, so go ahead and sign it. its an improvement, but in security, panacea's are few and far between, so signing is just one step of many to establish a secure infrastructure. you don't just leave your door unlocked because someone could conceivably kick a locked door down (or just break a window) rendering the lock less than 100% effective for all usecases.

Comment: @Rob - It is more secure. Users want to use signed files. Unsigned files are inherently insecure. A signed file is secure and easily verifiable to be legitimate. Only the creator of the installer can sign it. You indicated you were not the creator

Answer (score 0):

Signatures provide three main things when present on an installer:

- **Integrity:** The signature validation will fail if the content of the installer has changed at all
- **Identity:** The user can see who signed an installer
- **Trust:** Users may not get warnings when an installer is signed by a trusted publisher certificate

However, if an installer file gets entirely **replaced** as your friend saw, the new file will just have someone else's signature (or none at all). End users will see the same warnings they see now for untrusted/unsigned software, and may choose to ignore them.

For that reason, it **is** more secure to sign your software. Otherwise it will look no different from a malicious installer, which those warnings are there to help protect from.